# Error with Select statement in Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code :

```
getAllResult.GroupBy(g => g.OriginatingTransactionID)
.Select(r => 
{
    usp_GetAll_Result getAllResult1 = r.Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle
    {
        BundleName = getAllResult1.BundleName,
        BundleStatusCode = getAllResult1.BundleStatusCode,
        BundleStatusReasonCode = getAllResult1.BundleStatusReasonCode
    };
}).ToList();
```

I am getting the error while compiling:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: The function inside `Select` must return a value, and the return type of the `Select` method will be inferred from that returned value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.Select()` returns a value.  Currently you are not returning anything from your expression.

Just return your bundle.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle
                {
                    BundleName = getAllResult1.BundleName,
                    BundleStatusCode = getAllResult1.BundleStatusCode,
                    BundleStatusReasonCode = getAllResult1.BundleStatusReasonCode
                };

return bundle;
```